# How an external contract can access to my wrapped ether balance?

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I deployed a fork of uniswap in mainnet and I add to it some liquidity, creating a pair between ETH and my token. I made some swaps, and after some days I noticed that someone stole the liquidity, I reviewed the internal transactions of my contract and I noticed that a contract transfered the amount directly from wrapped ether contract without executing the method "removeLiquidity", how can be this possible? Someone has some time to give, if it needs, a paid advisory? In advance, thanks.

Comment: Can you share relevant details like contract address, transaction hash?

Comment: @pbsh look, here is the transaction hash 0x2bf2a3ccfba747f042f38ad3ae40903fa5620db3913452dda5a149526b532d00, and the Pair contract address is: 0xB50b6393005e6C95f7B8F77034377efA054c595F, and the liquidity provider (me): 0x50f76525d2283d43A244e93E7a0bC4ce20055f0E